# Finding direction of a vector

Tags: vectors

I'm watching an MIT lecture on multivariate calculus, and the proof says that given a vector $\vec{A}$, we can find its direction by "scaling the vector down to unit length" by dividing by its length. I don't understand how this gives its direction, and would be inclined instead to use trigonometry in the plane to solve for the angle $\theta$ made with the horizontal axis.

Could someone explain what he meant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We say vectors are quantities with magnitude and direction. By scaling to a unit vector (a vector with length one), we have lost the magnitude of the original vector but have preserved the direction. So unit vectors are a common way to describe directions. Angle with horizontal axis certainly works for two-dimensional vectors, but not practical for higher dimensions. This is why it is common to not teach vectors until we start discussing 3-dimensional space.

Comment: So the unit vector itself is the direction?

Comment: @StanleySmith Yes.