# Interpretation of the direction of a n-dimensional vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I am learning multivariate calculus, which makes me questioning my understanding of a vector. Can someone please give me an intuition for the direction of a vector in a general abstract term?

For example, what does the direction of the vector (1,2,-3,-4) mean? I tend to think of it as a "movement" such that from a given point, the 1st dimension changes by 1, the 2nd by 2, etc in some same amount of "time". This feels a bit unsettled to me since I have to use the mysterious notation of "time", which pops out from nowhere.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add your definition of the *direction* of a vector in $\Bbb R^n$? Is it the angle it makes with the x-axis? In Euclidean space, one can define a *direction vector* to be a vector $\vec u$ such that $|\vec u| = 1$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding direction of a vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4164268/finding-direction-of-a-vector)

Comment: Thank you for the response! I guess that's what my question is really about: what are the general definition and interpretation for the direction of a vector in Rn space? 
As indicated in the thread you suggested, for higher dimensional spaces, the definition by angles with the axis don't work anymore. As I understand, you can normalize a vector to focus only on the relative changes between components. But with respect to what are these changes?

Comment: For example, considering a scalar function f: R4-->R and a vector v that lives in the input space. The directional derivative of f along v at a given input point is the rate of change of f while the input moves at velocity vector v away from that given point (please correct me if I am wrong). But when we talk about the velocity, we need to clarify with respect to what.

I'm sorry for my limited math knowledge. I hope I don't confuse you as I confuse myself! :)